# Get mailchimp's Lists

Tags: php, mailchimp

I am using MailChimp api, and I want to get Mailchimp Lists. This is my php code to get the lists, which worked perfectly, but now it returns an empty result.

```
    $ch = curl_init('http://'.$value -> responce -> dc.'.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists?apikey='.$access_key);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE); 

    $res = curl_exec($ch);
```

Does anyone know why?

Comment: *Does anyone know why?* Well, just check the response it will tell why.

Comment: Try `var_dump($res);` at the end of your code.

Comment: Thanks Ahmed. I have tried it before than ask here. It returns nothing.